# loading saved tf model issue .. Tensorflow 2.0.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently installed anaconda 2020.02 on my Windows 10 laptop which comes with Spyder 4.0.1. .... then installed Tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0

`import tensorflow as tf 
trained_model=tf.saved_model.load(export_dir='model_folder') 
trained_model.summary()`

it fails with:

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'

Not even trained_model.fit is working. It said that there is no attribute 'fit'. 
Any suggestions please?